# Помощь с ida. apk файлы

Tags: android, ida-pro

Закинул .so файл в ida. Что нужно сделать чтобы увидеть классы или же пакеты от приложения?
Может быть у кого-то завалялся тутор)

Comment: Хедеры нужны для этого.

Answer (score 0):

.so-файл - это скомпилированная в машинный код библиотека (shared object), по аналогии как dll-файл в Windows. **Здесь нет java-классов и пакетов**.

О том, как получить C++-классы и С-структуры из бинарного файла можно почитать в книгах:

- Крис Касперски **"Искусство дизассемблирования"**
- Денис Юричев **"Reverse Engineering для начинающих"**